# React native app is enlarged on iPhone X and iPhone plus

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was following this tutorial (https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae) to set up a launch screen and deleted `launchScreen.xib`. Then my app is enlarged in iPhone X and iPhone plus:

[image]

Even the status bar is enlarged.
[image]

The top and bottom portions are left out on iPhone X. How should I fix this?

Comment: Create an iPhone X launch screen

Comment: ^This. You need a launchscreen of size: 1125px × 2436px